# How to create a pointer to member which does not perform virtual calls?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, pointer-to-member

```
#include <iostream>

struct CL1
{
    virtual void fnc(){std::cout<<1;}
};

struct CL2: CL1
{
    void fnc(){std::cout<<2;}
};


int main()
{
    auto pf = &CL1::fnc;
    CL1* pcl = new CL2;
    (pcl->*pf)(); //prints "2"
}
```

Here is a pointer to member function `fnc`, which calls version of a derived class. How can I create a pointer which points just to CL1::fnc, without using of a virtual table?

Comment: You can always call the CL1 version this way `pcl->CL1::fnc();`

Comment: I don't think it is possible, I've not seen any syntax that would differentiate virtual and non-virtual member functions.

Comment: Pointer to member always do late binding.